# C# delegate versus event handler

Tags: c#, events, delegates

What are some good considerations to decide between using an event handler and a delegate method?

For instance, I choose delegate methods option for deferring functionality implementation to another object. And I choose event handler option largely for the purpose of letting other objects to subscribe to updates.

But obviously, as you can see, these are very crude criteria. I've read a few similar questions on Stackoverflow but they are geared towards very specific issues whereas I am more interested in generic usage.

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "delegate methods"? It's very hard to compare two options without seeing an example of them, or even a scenario.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the format of this site. Questions are expected to not be prone to opinion/debate. You should refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Event handlers *are* delegates. If you're asking whether it's preferable to use actual events or to just publically expose a delegate, the answer is use events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above it will vary based on your circumstances.  `Delegates` used to require your logic to have a separate method to implement your logic.  Which made the usage of a `Delegate` difficult to justify.  However with `Lambda Expressions` and `Anonymous Methods` a `Delegate` actually becomes a very useful, powerful `Type` that is easy to justify.

`Delegates` are great for:

- Event Handlers
- Starting a Thread
- Callbacks
- LINQ

The conceptual notion of a template with special code, the `Delegate` is quite nice.

An `Event Handler` would be ideal when your looking for a `Class` to provide some form of notification when an `Object` is manipulated. The most common implementation and easiest example, would be a `User Interface`.  Each `Class` represents a `Control` and each `Control` in the `Interface` would have an event to indicate when a change is made.

A `Button` it's entire purpose is to be clicked; but you don't need it to perform or do anything until it is clicked.  An example of an `Event Handler`.

They often declared in nature by the usage of a `Delegate`.  The reasoning is `Delegate Object` encapsulates a method so that it may be called anonymously.  An `Event` is a way for a `Class` to allow clients to give a `Delegate` the methods that should be called when the `Event` occurs.

All an `Event Handler` is, is a procedure that is called to a correlated `Event`. These `Event Handlers` require two elements:

- A `Delegate`
- Optionally, a class to hold that `Event` data.

So in most cases, they go hand in hand.

Obviously your question doesn't provide much detail, so it becomes difficult to physically answer or hone in on your criteria.

Some sites to help you:

- [Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx)
- [Events and Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z7x8ys3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

These are both important concepts so it is very important to understand them.  Hopefully this helps clarify a bit.